# Do I write ".22 rifle" or "twenty-two rifle"?

Tags: numbers

I'm writing a fiction novel, and someone casually mentions a .22 rifle. In speech, you would just say "twenty-two rifle" (as opposed to "point-twenty-two rifle").

So, do I write out the number, or leave it as .22?

Edit: I'm talking about this in an American context, but the UK responses were also interesting. Thank you.

Comment: In BrE we say "point two two".

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This is largely a matter of style. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, adopt a [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579/16052)  appropriate to your audience and tastes, and be consistent in its application. For what it's worth, I read *.22* as *twenty-two caliber*.

Comment: If you want the character to say "twenty-two rifle" then write "twenty-two rifle". Written dialogue isn't a technical description of the things the characters are talking about, it is the actual words they're saying.

Comment: When I won a 2nd class marksman's badge in Alleyn's School CCF, it was with a Lee-Enfield .303 rifle converted to .22 calibre (using a 'Morris tube:). The British Army instructors called these weapons 'two-twos'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey those converted .22's were great fun. I also grew up saying '*seven-six-two*' and '*five-five-six*' for 7.62mm and 5.56mm rounds respectively. (5.56 being the [L98](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SA80#L98_Cadet_General_Purpose_Rifles) ammo)

Comment: Are you interested in US or UK English? There might be a difference.

Comment: It's a question of style and context and intention. If you're writing in a context where the precise nature of the firearm is significant, then write ".22"; if you're looking to express the words actually used then write the actual words as spoken. Some fiction takes what might be called an idea-based approach to dialog which records the gist of what is said (more or less precisely), other fiction will try and include all quirks, hesitation, accent/dialect pronunciations. I'm assuming you're reporting direct speech rather than indirect speech or narration, but you could make that explicit.

Comment: In British contexts, a spoken firearm calibre is often just each figure separately, omitting any 'point', so .22 inches is 'two-two' and .303 inches is 'three-oh-three'. The US .3030 inches calibre, adopted by NATO, which is expressed in metric as 7.62mm, is often said as 'seven-six-two'. A .50 inches calibre round is a 'half inch', but (as far as I know) the Colt .45 round is a 'forty-five'.

Comment: Actually the NATO '7.62mm' round is equivalent to the US .308 Winchester.

Comment: I have never, in the US, heard anyone refer to a .22 caliber firearm as anything other than a "twenty-two".  Likewise for "thirty-eight" and "forty-five".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm not familiar with firearms, so if I were reading a novel and it said

> "He had a .22 rifle," Bob remarked.

then I'd probably pause for a moment while I figured out how to pronounce ".22" in my head. On the other hand, if the novel said

> "He had a twenty-two rifle," Bob remarked.

then I'd be able to read it fluently without pausing, and I'd still understand the meaning just as easily.

Of course, not everyone actually imagines the characters speaking. (Perhaps most people don't.) But I don't see any reason not to write this out in dialogue.

Comment: The advantage with the first version is that Brits can imagine "point 2 2" and Americans can imagine "twenty-two."

Answer (score 5):

In any fiction I’ve read, if the caliber of a firearm was mentioned, it was always written out numerically, e.g., “a Colt .45”, “a .22 rifle for varmint hunting”, “a .38 Police Special”, “a 9mm Glock” which are corroborated by almost all examples found via Google Books ([Colt .45](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=colt+45), [22 rifle](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=22+rifle) )

(*I will note that I am American, and virtually all of the fiction I’ve read—mostly ‘thrillers’, SF, or ‘MilFic’—has conformed to American conventions, even if originally BrE [e.g., the Harry Potter novels, which do not mention firearms or their caliber].*)

Comment: But this is dialog, not narrative, where the conventions might be different.

Comment: @PeterShor - In what I've read, it hasn't mattered whether the weapon and caliber was mentioned in narrative or in dialogue - it's always been written out numerically (e.g., "What's he got?" "I saw a Colt .45 on his belt, but he's also got some kind of a long gun in a case, which I couldn't identify.").

Comment: @Jeff Zeitlin - "virtually all of the fiction I’ve read—mostly ‘thrillers’, SF, or ‘MilFic’—has conformed to American conventions, even if originally BrE" Yup, they often get edited for the US market, especially those which are not aiming to be 'literature', but the reverse is not often seen.

Comment: [Are you sure?](https://www.google.com/search?q=colt+forty+five&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS852US853&sxsrf=ALeKk01eg8NdjiG2xfLzAgGu0STczGZy4A:1588388707964&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjU58-FmZTpAhWUoHIEHVV-AokQ_AUoAXoECGwQCQ&biw=1709&bih=922)

Answer (score 1):

I have a little familiarity with firearms and I have never heard anyone call a *.22* rifle a *twenty-two*, always a *point two-two*, with *point* being optional.  My experience of firearms is limited to the UK and Europe.

If I heard (possibly even if I read) the expression *twenty-two rifle* I might think it was something like a *thirty-thirty* rifle, in which the first *thirty* is the calibre (0.30 inches) and the second *thirty* is the standard load, in grains, of the ammunition.

Then there is the expression *thirty-aught-six* or *30-06* which is a type of rifle ammunition.  Again, the *thirty* is the calibre, but the *aught-six* is the year of its introduction to use by the US Army (1906, rather than 2006).

I think that if OP is writing fiction they would be well advised to get this kind of detail right (and therefore stick to *.22* or *two-two* in this case).  To people to whom this kind of verisimilitude matters, it matters.  To the rest, they won't care either way.

Comment: Are you from England?  I’ve (AmE) only ever heard it pronounced “twenty two”.  With or without a following “caliber”.  So it’d be formally a twenty two caliber rifle. Or just a twenty-two when you want to go shoot tin cans.  It follows along with the forty-five and the thirty-eight.  So if writing for American audiences verisimilitude would dictate “twenty-two” :-)

Comment: *H___no*.  From Scotland.  And, as I observed above, my familiarity with firearms is based on this side of the Atlantic.